# Distinct counts with datediffs are not so distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to return a count of a singular ID and the number of minutes since the record was created.

I have this as a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  batchid AS 'ID'
, COUNT(batchid) AS 'Count'
, DATEDIFF (MINUTE,CONVERT(char(10),MIN([createdOn]), 108),CONVERT(char(10),GETDATE(), 108))
FROM [UpdateRecords]
WHERE [status] = 'Pending'
GROUP BY batchId,createdOn
ORDER BY batchId
```

It returns the ID, the Count and the Minutes.

```
ID      Count  Minutes
171836  1      28
171836  4      28
171836  10     28
171836  21     28
```

The problem arises that the same ID will appear multiple times.
When added together, the count for that ID is accurate.

I would like a distinct count, by ID, along with the minutes

ID      Count  Minutes
171836  36     28

How can I do this using minutes? Can this be done displaying hours and minutes?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Why are you converting date/times to *strings* and then using `datediff()`???  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by the same items in your Select:

```
SELECT 
batchid AS 'ID'
, COUNT(batchid) AS 'Count'
, DATEDIFF (MINUTE,CONVERT(char(10),MIN([createdOn]), 108),CONVERT(char(10),GETDATE(), 108))
FROM [UpdateRecords]
WHERE [status] = 'Pending'
GROUP BY batchId, DATEDIFF (MINUTE,CONVERT(char(10),MIN([createdOn]), 108),CONVERT(char(10),GETDATE(), 108))
ORDER BY batchId
```

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, since the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: Jen R is correct.  Just to add a little depth, the reason why you're getting multiple lines for each ID is that you're telling the query to group by createdon, which means that each unique combination of batchID and createdon will produce a row.  You can also omit the DISTINCT now, as the aggregation will already produce a set of distinct rows.

Comment: I removed the `distinct` - I was in a hurry unfortunately and just corrected the `group by` from the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT batchid AS ID,
       COUNT(*) AS Count,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(time, createdOn), CONVERT(time, GETDATE()))
FROM UpdateRecords
WHERE status = 'Pending'
GROUP BY batchId
ORDER BY batchId
```